# How can I connect to SAS CAS Server

Tags: python, sas, yolo

I am working on Training image dataset in SAS using YOLO. I am following a documentation where the steps are given (please refer to the reference documentation link given below.

However, now I am struggling as I could not finish establishing connection to SAS CAS server as it shows an error.

This is the code I gave:

```
# Connect to the SAS CAS Server

s =     CAS('pdcesx23043.exnet.sas.com', 5570)
```

and it rendered the following error:

```
    ERROR: Kerberos initialization failed. Your credential cache is either expired or missing.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/swat/cas/connection.py in 
    __init__(self, hostname, port, username, password, session, locale, nworkers, name, authinfo, protocol, path, ssl_ca_list, authcode, **kwargs)
    436                 else:
--> 437                     self._sw_connection = clib.SW_CASConnection(*params)
    438 

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/swat/clib.py in SW_CASConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    132         _import_pyswat()
--> 133     return _pyswat.SW_CASConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    134 

     SystemError: <class 'py38swat.SW_CASConnection'> returned NULL without setting an error

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     SWATError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7f4ffa2dc158> in <module>
      1 # Connect to the SAS CAS Server
      2 
----> 3 s = CAS('pdcesx23043.exnet.sas.com', 5570)

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/swat/cas/connection.py in 
    __init__(self, hostname, port, username, password, session, locale, nworkers, name, authinfo, protocol, path, ssl_ca_list, authcode, **kwargs)
    442 
    443         except SystemError:
--> 444             raise SWATError(self._sw_error.getLastErrorMessage())
    445 
    446         # Set up index origin for error messages

    SWATError: Could not connect to 'pdcesx23043.exnet.sas.com' on port 5570.
```

It would be a great help if you could look into this issue and give me guidance to fix the problem.

[Reference documentation link](https://github.com/sassoftware/python-dlpy/blob/master/examples/object_detection/PrepareObjectDetectionTable.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for the tip,

I have modified my question accordingly.

Comment: And on the line before and the line after the code or log, put quadruple `, so it is formatted as code. (I did it for you.)

Comment: It looks like you are accessing SAS from python. Please add a `python` tag and mention what you imported.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an authinfo file set up, or are you using Kerberos?  The error at the top of the first seems like a kerberos issue, but it may actually be an issue with authinfo - see the [troubleshooting documentation](https://sassoftware.github.io/python-swat/troubleshooting.html).

It should be possible to use kerberos, but it's very finicky, and you'll likely need your SAS admin and your AD admin to both help get the connections set up properly.

Authinfo is the more common solution, as it caches your password, and you should be able to find [instructions here](https://documentation.sas.com/api/collections/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/docsets/authinfo/content/authinfo.pdf?locale=en).